# How to directly access MongoDB API from Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'd like to use the [addToSet](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24addToSet) method of MongoDB, but Mongoid doesn't currently support this yet. Is there a way of directly accessing the MongoDB driver from my Rails model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked this question [on Mongoid group](http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/abc559094c775f36) and this was the best response:

> Assuming your model object is a Mongoid::Document, simply call the
>   "db" method on it to get a handle to the Mongo::DB object that Mongoid
>   is using under the hood.
>
> [http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Collections/Cl...](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Collections/ClassMethods%23db-instance_method)
>
> From there, you can use the MongoDB Ruby driver API directly.
>
> http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html#

Also, you can access the record collection using ModelName.collection.

Comment: looks like the `db` method is out and the `collection` method is in!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mongo-ruby-driver gem from mongodb:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver

Check the update method in the api:

http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.2.0/Mongo/Collection.html#update-instance_method

And this option might be what you're looking for to use *addToSet*:

```
(Boolean) :upsert — default: +false+ — if true, performs an upsert (update or insert)
```

Answer (score 0):

Up to and including Mongoid 2.4 you could access the database object with

```
db = Mongoid.master
```

Comment: This doesn't work with 3+.  `MyModel.collection.database`, however, does